# Instance Store in AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

For one of my hadoop deployments I'm taking previous generation instances (m1,xlarge, m1.large etc).m1.xlarge instance comes with 4X420 GiB instance store. Is instance store is safer to store data or do i need to go for EBS?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much persistence you want for your data (or how you would define safer). The instance store will be lost if the instance is terminated or stopped. You also have the risk of AWS "losing" your instance if you plan to run them for a long time (in my case, I've seen instances fail after approximately one year, however we've had instances run flawlessly for over 3 years).

So if you need persistance, go with EBS and, if needed, compensate performance differences by using EBS with provisioned IOPS or an RAID array of EBS volumes. If your use case is just importing data, crunching it in hadoop and exporting it somewhere else, you can safely choose the instance store (we're doing this using EMR, for example).